# counting the syllables function

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to write a function that counts the syllables in any given word. But I've hit a block and I dont know what else to do. The word has to be separated by a dash like this "-" wherever a syllable count should be counted. Anyone who can help i would appreciate it. I would also prefer that instead of giving me brand new code. Please tell me what i need for my code so it performs the way intended. Thank you so much everyone.

```
const numberSyllables = (str) => {
    let dashPos = []; //this will take in the indices of the dashes
    let parent = [] //I planned on taking the letters that come before, after. or between the dashes and making them into an array that I would push into this array. Basically have a nested array.
    let dashedPosition; //The dashPos array will have the join() method applied to it. The output will be assigned to this variable


    for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
      if(str[i] === '-'){
        dashPos.push(i);
        dashedPosition = dashPos.join() //This returns the indices of the '-'. It works well
       
       for(let i = 0; i < dashPos.length; i++){
         parent.push(str.substring(str[i], dashPos[i]).split(", ")) //Retrieves elements all the way up to but not including the first '-'
        // Had trouble retrieving the elements that come after the '-'. Also if there are multiple '-' that come after the first one. It needs to know that it has to exclude them and only collect the group of elements before the dashes or after or in between.
  
         console.log(parent)
        
       }
      }
      
    } 
    return parent.length //This should give the syllable count. It will have within it arrays of elements that come before, after, or in between the '-'. So the number of those nested arrays is the syllable count
  }

//Example of what the outputs should be:
numberSyllables("buf-fet") ➞ 2

numberSyllables("beau-ti-ful") ➞ 3

numberSyllables("mon-u-men-tal") ➞ 4

numberSyllables("on-o-mat-o-poe-ia") ➞ 6
```

Comment: The goal is literally to count dashes? I'd tend toward `str.replace(/[^-]/g, "").length` for that. Or if not, just a `for` loop (`for-of` if supported in your target environment) with a counter you increment when you see `-`.

Comment: @ggorlen - I did, but note [this](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-replaceall). ;-) Must have been on my mind from finishing Chapter 19 recently...

Comment: Can you not use `str.split("-").length` ?

Comment: Note that your question and what you're _actually_ doing are not the same thing, and for a good question it's important to notice that difference. Your text plus code basically suggest you want to count dashes in a string. While that may have started life as "trying to count syllables", what you _actually_ want to know is not related to syllables at all.

Comment: @birwin that's the obvious answer, you should post it

Comment: @Taplar remember that `x` syllables are separated by `x-1` dashes, so `str.split("-").length` would get you the correct syllable count.

Comment: The OP explicitly asks for help understanding why their logic does not work. So that should be a part of an answer.

Comment: Taplar - I think just length... If there are no dashes in the word, the length would be one, which matcfhes the number of syllables. If there is one dash, I believe the length would be two, which is the correct number of syllables... Also, @mmfallacy posted the answer about the same time I commented, so let's all upvote his post as he is a new contributor.

Comment: Honestly? Not really, no. The solution here is a one liner, and the proper fix to their code _really is_ "use that one-liner". It's not "let's make this massive block of code do this task less efficiently, more confusingly, and with a much larger potential bug surface".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans "just do this" does not teach them what they are doing wrong originally.  It avoids the issue.  There is no reason why we, who may already know what the issue is, should hoard that knowledge to ourselves.  That's part of why this place exists.

Comment: Writing tons of code where the standard library already offers a single function call is part of what can be done wrong, though, and that's a lesson that's worth learning early on. The right answer here does not teach them how to fix their code - that'd be a bad answer for future visitors, which is what makes SO so useful. If you post a question here, that question is never just "for you", it's "for everyone".

Comment: I disagree that explaining to an OP, who explictly asks for the information on what they are doing wrong, is the incorrect approach.  A good answer, in fact a great answer, does both.  Explains what they are doing wrong **and** points out a better way of doing it.

Comment: can't give a definite answer to where he went wrong tho, since I don't quite get what OP expects parent to output. It'd be handy if OP will give a sample output for parent

Comment: @mmfallacy From the comments in the code, I'm guessing `parent` would equal something like this at the end: `[ ["b","e","a","u"], ["t","i"], ["f","u","l"] ]`

Comment: @blex yes parent is expected to do that. And thank you everyone for the responses! I’m self learning Javascript so apologies for the unnecessarily complicated code 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const numberSyllables = (str) => str.split('-').length;

console.log( numberSyllables("buf-fet") ); // 2
console.log( numberSyllables("beau-ti-ful") ); // 3
console.log( numberSyllables("mon-u-men-tal") ); // 4
console.log( numberSyllables("on-o-mat-o-poe-ia") ); // 6
```

Basically if you split the string by `-` it'll return to you an array of all the syllables, so getting the count of that array will give you the number of syllables.

Comment: so the split method creates arrays from strings at specified parts of the string too? Like how u  did by putting the '-' into the split method?

Comment: @KazimShabbir Yes, for example, `"beauhellotihelloful".split("hello")` will return `["beau", "ti", "ful"]`. Then, if you take its length, you have the number of elements separated by "hello"